# The correct procedure for preventing access to web pages if login details haven't been entered PHP

Tags: php, web-applications, redirect, session-variables

I am in the process of making a secure Web application on a remote server. Is there a industry standard of preventing users from accessing web pages that are only available to users who have posted their login details.

So far authenticated user pages are protected using simple header redirects if the user do sent hold a session variable.

Is this industry standard? Are there better ways to implement such a method.

pysedo code

```
 Session code dosent equal value or session is null {

     header redirect to index 

}
```

Comment: Headers can be ignored. It should not be the only way normal access is prevented.

Comment: @Ikke how can headers be ignored?

Comment: Normal browser will follow them, but anyone who wants to get access to a resource can use custom clients or tools to just request that page without following any Location headers.

Comment: Just as a side remark: if you really set out to the quest of "making a secure web application", then why rely on something like an industry standard? Leading applications and frameworks show security flaws again and again, so it makes little sense to rely on some strategy commonly regarded as "secure". If you really want to make something secure you try to solve the issue of securing something that is unsecure by design (the web).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, redirect headers are not a security feature in their own. After you have sent a redirect header, you should make sure that normal execution can't happen.

For example:

```
if($username != "foo" && $password != "bar")
{
    header('Location: http://domain.org/index.php');
}

echo "Authorized page";
```

Even if the username and password are not correct, the contents of this page can still be accessed by just ignoring the `Location` header.

A simple fix would be:

```
if($username != "foo" && $password != "bar")
{
    header('Location: http://domain.org/index.php');
    die("Redirecting to home page");
}

echo "Authorized page";
```

Furthermore, it's important that authentication doesn't rely on manual checks on each page, because these checks can easily be forgotten by developers. Try to automate these kind of things as much as possible.

Comment: That's why people use `exit;` immediately after sending headers such as location one.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to tell.

Comment: @lkke Good post, what is a general example of automating these checks if its okay to ask?

Comment: @MatthewUnderwood Using a framework can help. They often have means to  execute things on every request for example.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I understand the question correct.

However maybe this helps: 
Since the web server handles authentication in a pretty good manner (provided it is configured correct) there is only hotlinking left. You can try to catch that issue by additional redirect rules in the server configuration: if the HTTP_REFERER is not a previously authenticated page, then redirect to wherever.

There is nothing more I can think of. 
The important thing is to get authentication right and safe at the beginning.

Comment: Things like referer can be easily spoofed. Don't rely on it's value for security purposes.

Comment: @Ikke Whilst it is true that it can be spoofed it is a valid protection against hotlinking. This is what I said. Same tactics as a CSRF protection token which works reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a good solution, but I simply keep the login status in session variables:

```
if ($_SESSION[loggedIn] == "yes"  && $_SESSION["LevelTwoPermissions"] == "yes")
{
    // Grant access to allowed content...
}
else
{
    // Redirect to login page or ask for login in a pop-up
}
```

It could theoretically be hacked by stealing session cookie from an other user, but it's a reasonable level of security for my purposes.